# Find string in list of strings

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a set of lists of items `FreqItemsets`, for example :

```
FreqItemset(items=[u'bbb_1', u'ccc_1', u'ccc_2', u'aaa_1', u'ccc_3'], freq=379)
FreqItemset(items=[u'aaa_1_1', u'ccc_1', u'ccc_2', u'ccc_3'], freq=375)
...
```

I try to find in each `FreqItemset` an item starts from  `aaa`

I know how to find `aaa` in first element of the list

```
filtered_result = model.freqItemsets()\
 .filter(lambda x: x.items[0].startswith('aaa_')).collect()
```

The question is how to find `aaa` in each element of `FreqItemset`?

In first line of example above `aaa` string in forth place.

I thought about something like this :

```
   filtered_result = model.freqItemsets()\
     .filter(lambda x: x.items[0].startswith('aaa_'))
     .filter(lambda x: x.items[1].startswith('aaa_'))
     .filter(lambda x: x.items[2].startswith('aaa_'))
     ...
     .collect()
```

is it most efficient way?

Comment: Those `items` are not lists of sets. Those are lists of unicode strings. Do you know how to do this with a 'normal' list (Python's default datatype `list`)? That would be a starting point in combination with so called `list comprehensions`.

Comment: @albert  if you know the answer please provide it

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not have the datatype `FreqItemset` I am just demonstrating a general approach using Python's default datatype `list`:

```
list_1 = [u'bbb_1', u'ccc_1', u'ccc_2', u'aaa_1', u'ccc_3']
list_2 = [u'aaa_1_1', u'ccc_1', u'ccc_2', u'ccc_3']

results_1 = [s for s in list_1 if s.startswith('aaa')]
results_2 = [s for s in list_2 if s.startswith('aaa')]

print(results_1)
print(results_2)
```

Since I am using Python 3 and it looks like you're using Python 2, you need to change `print(something)` into `print something`.

*Note:*
You can adapt this general approach in order to all that stuff kind of less manual e.g. iterating over a list of lists (or `FreqItemset`s in your case). Or write the results into a dictionary containing e.g. the different frequencies as keys.

Comment: could it be like `.filter(s for s in items if items.startswith('aaa_'))` ?

Comment: I have never used any `filter()` function. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct, you want to filter those elements consisting only of certain strings. It looks like a job for [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
itemsets.filter(lambda x: all(i.startswith('aaa_') for i in x.items))
```

Which I'd rather extract to a new function:

```
def is_good(itemset):
    return all(i.startswith('aaa_') for i in x.items)

itemsets.filter(is_good)
```

Comment: @berael Thanks a lot for answering . Unfortunately I get error : `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

Comment: @Toren fixed, should be `x.items` in the loop.

Comment: Many thanks,  nice solution ! спасибо ! Please fix solution : change from `all` to `any` . I'll vote then . Nice work .

Comment: @Toren applying multiple filters is `and` operation, therefore, it's `all`, not `any`.

Comment: `all` not works in , my case , because it keeps list with all elements starts with `aaa_` , otherwise `any` works because any element in list can start with `aaa_` . I've verified this in my code .